# Set Container height equal to width in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am learning Flutter development. I want to display some rounded square shaped containers with short text in a row. However, the possible shapes are either a circle or rectangle. So I decided to set the width and height of the rectangle so that they would be equal.
The following is the code I used to create the Container

```
Container(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      height: 
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: ThemeProvider.themeOf(context).data.primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Text(keyText),
    ),
```

When I set the shape in Box decoration alone, the Container resized to the size of the text. When I set the width property of the Container, I was able to divide the available width of the screen among the containers, which ensures flexibility of size if the screen was smaller or bigger, instead of hard coding it. Now I want to make the height the exact same size that the width turns out to be, thus obtaining a square container. Any idea how I could do that?

EDIT: I tried the following code and this is how the containers are looking like in both cases:

```
Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: double.maxFinite,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: ThemeProvider.themeOf(context).data.primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),

Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: ThemeProvider.themeOf(context).data.primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
```

[After using MediaQuery.of(context).size.width for height property or both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4QD2.png)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a solution without using MediaQuery:

```
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 1,
  child: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Text(),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked perfectly. All I had to do was wrap my containers with it. EDIT: For anyone who passes by, I decided to wrap all the containers in a GridView.count instead of a Row, and specified how many containers to appear in each row using the crossAxisCount property. I also set the shrinkWrap property to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: ThemeProvider.themeOf(context).data.primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Text(keyText),
    ),
```

Comment: Is you save in both width and height as MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

Answer (score 0):

Use `MediaQuery`. `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` gives you the Screen width size value.

```
Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: ThemeProvider.themeOf(context).data.primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Text(keyText),
    )
```

Comment: I want the width of the container to be whatever it can get after dividing the screen width among all containers. As I am placing the containers in a row, I am using a mainAxisSize.min and a mainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly. Each Container is wrapped in an Expanded widget

Comment: are you using a GridView? or can you share a screenshot of how the containers are arranged?

Answer (score 0):

check this quick example that I made just for you!

```dart
  // This function is just an example
  List<Widget> buildContainers(BuildContext context, int containerCount) {
    // Here you get the width of all your containers
    final containerWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / containerCount;
    // Make height = width for squares!
    final containerHeight = containerWidth;
    // We will gather all containers in this list
    List containerList = <Container>[];

    for (var i = 0; i < containerCount; i++) {
      containerList.add(
        Container(
          // Use the predefined width and height here!
          width: containerWidth, 
          height: containerHeight,
          // Random color to differentiate each container
          // You could replace this with your child widget
          color: Color(
            Random().nextInt(0xFFFFFFFF),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return containerList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          // If you are wondering what are these dots (...)
          // they are called "spread operators" and you can find more about them here:
          // https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator
          ...buildContainers(context, 7),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I tried it out, its a good way if I wanted to position the containers right next to each other.  I wanted my containers to be a bit spaced out. Any idea how I could include the padding in the calculation? Its like whatever the final width turns out to be, that's what the height should be as well. Also, I tried using the spread-operator, but it says that it requires spread-collections experiment to be enabled.

Comment: Its okay, I figured out I can add up all the constant padding, and remove it from the MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, before dividing the actual available space among the containers. Thanks!